# PHP json_encode json with variation of array. JSON Sometimes do not appear in firebug as JSON

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, json

Does JSON like any specific array structure?

when it is used in

```
$value['date'][0] = "12-21-2012";
$value['name'][1] = "Joe";
echo json_encode($value);
```

it seems to detect JSON under firebug

however, when it is switched around firebug does not seem to see it as JSON

```
$value[0]['date'] = "12-21-2012";
$value[1]['name'] = "Joe";
echo json_encode($value);
```

is it behaving normally?

Comment: The first one becomes an object and the second is an array.  That'd shouldn't be an issue, but they are not the same structure, so you need to access them differently.  What do the 2 echo when you `json_encode` them?

Comment: Thanks!  Been using echo json_encode($value) for most of the time now. under PHP it does not seem to output the actual JSON data if you do not add "echo" command.   it basically outputs the data with echo command

Comment: `json_encode` just returns a string.  If you don't `echo` it, it doesn't get displayed.